# Handling circular dependency in rails while using threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

Here are five files added to [my app](https://github.com/pratik60/circular_dependency_havoc) (no database, no setup as such required):

lib/tasks/precomputation.rake

```
namespace :precomputation do
  desc "This fetches data for precomputation"
  task fetch_all: :environment do
      Precomputation.precompute_all_data
    # end
  end
end
```

app/models/precomputation.rb

```
class Precomputation
  def self.precompute_all_data
    ad_accounts = [1,2,3]
    bgthread = BackgroundThread::BGThreadPool.new(1)
    tasks = []
    ad_accounts.each do |ad_account_id|
      p = Proc.new do
        begin
          MongoPipeline::FbAdCampaignMongoPipeline.new(ad_account_id).fetch_all
          false
        ensure
          GC.start
        end
      end
      tasks << [p, "test #{ad_account_id}"]
    end
    bgthread.add_randomized_tasks(tasks)
    bgthread.do_work
  end
end
```

app/models/mongo_pipeline.rb

```
module MongoPipeline
  class Base
    def initialize(ad_account_id)
    end

    def insert_data
      puts 'inserting data'
    end

    def fetch_all
      extract_data # Child Class defines this method
      insert_data # Base class defines this method
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/mongo_pipeline/fb_ad_campaign_mongo_pipeline.rb

```
module MongoPipeline
  class FbAdCampaignMongoPipeline < MongoPipeline::Base
    def extract_data
      puts 'here is campaign data'
    end
  end
end
```

and app/models/background_thread.rb

(NOTE: Alternative implementation using parallel gem and no background thread also collapses with similar error -: https://github.com/pratik60/circular_dependency_havoc/tree/parallel)

Error log

```
rake aborted!
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MongoPipeline
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/webapps/circular_dependency_havoc/app/models/precomputation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in precompute_all_data'
/webapps/circular_dependency_havoc/app/models/background_thread.rb:91:in `call'
/webapps/circular_dependency_havoc/app/models/background_thread.rb:91:in `block in background'
Tasks: TOP => precomputation:fetch_all
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? The background thread library was cloned and just modified. Feel free to replace it if you think that's the problem. Any suggestions, any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Threads and autoload do not work well together. Could you run this in the production environment instead of the development environment?

Comment: @SteveJorgensen Nope, no luck. Are there other libraries which I might wanna use?

Answer (score 4):

I came across this issue when building a threaded loops in a rake task to poll external servers, and came to the same conclusion that it was Autoload & unpredictable race-condition related. However I did not want to simply turn eager loading on, so there were two ways I addressed this. One was to figure out which classes were getting loaded in my task and load them in the parent, ahead of spawning any threads:

```
# preload classes that showed circular dependencies just in this task
MediaFile
VideoPlatformIntegration
Tag

10.times.map{Thread.new{...}}
```

This worked like a charm, but was slightly odd to put in production code and is not robust to any changes in the task or any methods invoked by it.

The other is more imperfect but only actually modifies behavior in the development environment and doesn't rely on knowing everything that might lead to this condition. Since it's only in development, I considered this acceptable: sleep for a random amount of time (between 0 and 1 seconds) at the start of each initial thread:

`sleep(Random.rand) if Rails.env == "development"`

This sleep prevent the threads from starting at the same time and drastically reduces the chance of any race condition in loading classes. I proof-of-concept this here using a simple batch of 10 threads, running the script 4 times with and 4 times without the sleep, showing a reliable Circular Dependency error without the sleep:

```
[video_platform_integration] andrew@~/3p/app3$ rails runner '10.times.map{Thread.new{MediaFile.last rescue puts($!)}}'
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MediaFile
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MediaFile
[video_platform_integration] andrew@~/3p/app3$ rails runner '10.times.map{Thread.new{MediaFile.last rescue puts($!)}}'
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MediaFile
[video_platform_integration] andrew@~/3p/app3$ rails runner '10.times.map{Thread.new{MediaFile.last rescue puts($!)}}'
[video_platform_integration] andrew@~/3p/app3$ rails runner '10.times.map{Thread.new{MediaFile.last rescue puts($!)}}'
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MediaFile
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MediaFile
[video_platform_integration] andrew@~/3p/app3$ rails runner '10.times.map{Thread.new{sleep(Random.rand); MediaFile.last rescue puts($!)}}'
[video_platform_integration] andrew@~/3p/app3$ rails runner '10.times.map{Thread.new{sleep(Random.rand); MediaFile.last rescue puts($!)}}'
[video_platform_integration] andrew@~/3p/app3$ rails runner '10.times.map{Thread.new{sleep(Random.rand); MediaFile.last rescue puts($!)}}'
[video_platform_integration] andrew@~/3p/app3$ rails runner '10.times.map{Thread.new{sleep(Random.rand); MediaFile.last rescue puts($!)}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially changed this setting

```
config/environments/development.rb

config.eager_load = true
```

This didn't help though!

And I needed to add

```
config/initializers/eager_load.rb:

Rails.application.eager_load! unless Rails.env.test?
```

You also need to eager load the entire lib folder, if you are using one (autoload isn't enough).

```
config/application.rb

config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Also, make sure that if devise is used in initializer it is renamed to 01_devise.rb or something, as initializers are loaded alphabetically, and your User or Admin, will reference it.

Probably suggest that in tests eager_load is skipped as it is suboptimal, and if you are not using threads internally, skip it altogether!